# How to include a custom web.config file in Sharepoint 2010 Project Solution

Tags: sharepoint

I created a Visual Web Part Project in which I want to include a custom web.config file to maintain the settings of my webpart. Steps I followed were: Clicked on Add xml file, renamed it to web.config  and Then included the appsettings in this file and tried to use it my code.

It did not allow me to do so. Can you please list out the steps to include a custom web.config file in a project.

Comment: Storing web part configuration in web.config is almost certainly the wrong thing to do - see Sylvian's answer for better options.

Comment: I would appreciate the point raise Sylvian but still would not appreciate the down votes on the answers AS CBono is answer is correct. and their could be situation when you need to update the webconfig from webparts a simple scenario to update a connection string in web.config. the connection string is used across the site collections and you need to provide a admin area from where you can update it. Since the users request was not clear the answers can not be treated as bad one

Comment: @Ashutosh - why so defensive? Thats the whole point of SO - people vote for what they think is the best answer. Sure the OP asked about web.config but that still doesn't mean its the best answer. Is doing the wrong thing correctly still wrong? I think so.

Comment: Oh and the connection string example is still lacking - what about a web farm with multiple WFE? Going to update the connection string on all web.config individually, or even worse hard code the connection string in the solution? Or would farm properties be a better bet?

Comment: @Ryan: Granted, you have a point. But the OP doesn't mention what settings are under consideration. Yes, SO lets you downvote bad answers, but I don't think any answers here are "bad". Why not just upvote the answer you think is best and let the poster decide?

Comment: @CBono - I didn't say BAD - just the web.config option IMHO is not as as GOOD as the other options (I still can't think of a reason where it would be) and as things stood you answer was 'on top'. I felt strongly enough about the (de)merits of the web.config option to loose my own rep - nothing personal mind! Having said that you put a well researched and referenced answer on so it is harsh I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want to put this settings on the web.config ?

The web.config is shared across all sites, site collections... on a webapplication.
Are you sure it is the right scope ?
It is also difficult to maintain and to update.

You have other solutions :

- Storing your settings into the properties of your webpart
- Storing your settings into the property bag of the SPWeb object
- Storing your settings into a custom list...

Here are some useful links :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798488.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647766.aspx

http://spconfigstore.codeplex.com/

Comment: +1 for seeing beyond the question. There are very very few valid reasons to be putting 'web part configuration' in web.config.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to include a custom web.config file for a SharePoint web part.

What you need to do is create an [`SPFeatureReceiver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfeaturereceiver.aspx), attach it to the feature definition inside your web part deployment package (i.e. WSP file), and have the receiver add the appropriate web.config entries on feature activation. To do this, you should use the [`SPWebConfigModification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebconfigmodification.aspx) class to add the entries on feature activation and remove them on feature deactivation.

Answer (score 0):

kindly go through the article link provided below

http://claytonj.wordpress.com/2008/03/19/custom-webconfig-settings-in-sharepoint/

hope this helps

Comment: To save you (the reader) a click, the linked post suggests the same technique as CBono suggests in his answer. Using SPWebConfigModification is what I would suggest as well.